# What is wrong with this jpql query?(JPA)

Tags: java, sql, jpa, java-ee-6, jpql

Can you help me find the error in my JPQL query of the login method in my application please?

```
// Login
public boolean saveUserState(String email, String password) {
    // 1-Send query to database to see if that user exist
    Query query = em
            .createQuery("SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE r.email=:emailparam r.password=:passwordparam");
    query.setParameter("emailparam", email);
    query.setParameter("passwordparam", password);
    // 2-If the query returns the user(Role) object, store it somewhere in
    // the session
    Role role = (Role) query.getSingleResult();
    if (role != null && role.getEmail().equals(email)
            && role.getPassword().equals(password)) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getSessionMap().put("userRole", role);
        // 3-return true if the user state was saved
        return true;
    }
    // 4-return false otherwise
    return false;
}
```

I am getting this error when it executes:

> SEVERE: JSF1073:
>   javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException
>   caught during processing of
>   INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 :
>   UIComponent-ClientId=j_idt13:j_idt17,
>   Message=/WEB-INF/templates/BasicTemplate.xhtml
>   @61,63
>   actionListener="#{securityController.logIn()}":
>   javax.ejb.EJBException SEVERE:
>   /WEB-INF/templates/BasicTemplate.xhtml
>   @61,63
>   actionListener="#{securityController.logIn()}":
>   javax.ejb.EJBException
>   javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException:
>   /WEB-INF/templates/BasicTemplate.xhtml
>   @61,63
>   actionListener="#{securityController.logIn()}":
>   javax.ejb.EJBException
>   .............................. Caused
>   by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An
>   exception occurred while creating a
>   query in EntityManager:  Exception
>   Description: Syntax error parsing the
>   query [SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE
>   r.email=:emailparam,
>   r.password=:passwordparam], line 1,
>   column 46: syntax error at [,].
>   Internal Exception:
>   MismatchedTokenException(79!=-1)

Comment: @Facepalmed Hey dude, Chilax! I've written this question 4yrs ago. And yes I did try it then. That of yours wasn't a very constructive comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query the link between the WHERE clauses is missing. Add an `AND` or an `OR` between both clauses:

```
SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE r.email=:emailparam AND r.password=:passwordparam
```

Answer (score 5):

You probably forgot to add `AND` or `OR`

like:

```
Query query = em
            .createQuery("SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE r.email=:emailparam AND r.password=:passwordparam");
```